# 2 tables with foreign keys to 3rd table with primary key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key

This might be a silly question.
But can you have the following:

1 Table with *Primary Key*,
2 different tables each with a *foreign key* referencing the first table *Primary key*?

I know its possible to have 2 foreign keys in the same table, but the request I received was for the the below scenario:

[image]

Comment: It is absolutely common situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be possible? Suppose table1 holds all countries, table2 all cities and table3 has another *foreign key* to a table with all international organisations. They both need a *foreign key* to a country. You can even have a table4 that holds all regions. It also needs a *foreign key* to table1.

Comment: I kept on receiving error, dropped and recreated table with FK constraint and it went through. Like i said, silly question, But thanks for clarifying

Comment: There are no silly questions. Only silly answers :-)